# C# MVC getting database permissions from user login

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm wondering what the proper way is to handle SQL permissions and store connection strings is in a C# MVC application.

Up until now I have done work around Windows authentication, so it has been set as such in the web.config connection string to use windows authentication and all database calling and writing has been done via the database context referencing that.

```
 <add name="ConnectionStringName" connectionString="data source=SqlDB;          initial catalog=DBNAME;persist security info=True;           Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

> > public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
> >         {
> >
> > ```
> >     public DatabaseContext() : base("name = ConnectionStringName")
> >     {
> >
> >     }
> > ```
>
> ... ...

controller code sample

```
public class MyController : Controller
    {
        public DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();

        // GET: 
        public ActionResult myView()
        {
            NewMmodel model = new NewModel();

            model.table = db.table.ToList(); 

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add([Bind(Include ="MyModel")] Add model)
        {
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC dbo.usp....
```

I now need to make something that people login with a username and password and will pull permissions from there.

My first thought would have been to make the web.config connection string "Dynamic" but it doesn't seem that this is possible? so probably not the proper way of doing it even if it is then?

Is it same to store a persisted username and password in a main connection string to allow initial reading from a database? if so is it then best to create a connection string in a class?

so in a data access layer class have something like:

```
public ProcessContext() : base(ConnectionString())
        {

        }

        private static string ConnectionString()
        {
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            sqlBuilder.DataSource = "XXX";
            sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = "YYY";
            sqlBuilder.PersistSecurityInfo = true;
            sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = false;
            sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
            sqlBuilder.UserID = "xxx";
            sqlBuilder.Password = "yyy";


            return sqlBuilder.ToString();
        }
```

I'm getting an error with this though saying ProcessContext() **Must have a return type**

If I am on the right track, finally what I want to be able to do is replace the USERID and password values above with the ones the user has logged in with.

I'm using the pre-built code visual studio pulls in with mvc 5 for the manual login.

I believe it comes from the SetupAuth.cs file and users the tables like AspNetUsers, roles Logins & Claims that it creates itself.

I can't really see where you can access those session values, I just need to add the **[Authorize]** tag above a call in the controller to check for a correct login.

Hope this all makes sense! Is this Owin/OAuth? everything i try to look at regarding OAuth talks about google or facebook login...

Comment: Definitely don't make the connString dynamic, you don't want users dictating where you get your data. Keep that consistent and then use something like ASP.Net identity to check the provided username/password against a table. This will work alongside the `[Authorize]` decorator. You can then implement Claims per user as you see fit.

Comment: thanks, so is the part of creating a private connection string in a Data access layer the correct method? what has been done wrong to give the error must have a return type?

Comment: @Demon - not so much.  [Authorize] just gives permissions to the part of the controller?.  I want to be able to pass in the username and password so when it does work on the database it uses those credentials.  Validates against the schema etc as an additional layer of security...

Comment: I'd encourage you not to mix and match security like that or rely on SQL server for your authentication. Instead use a service account for your connection to the SQL server and authenticate and authorize the user in the MVC app. You are already trusting your app to get the correct username and password, so it's really not adding any extra security and just adding more of a maintenance headache.

Comment: Ok thanks, so storing a persisted username and password in the web.config is safe though?

Comment: It's pretty common practice. It's arguably better to store it in various environment variables instead (inside IIS or whatever other hosting you are using)